# python append object to a list

Tags: python, list, object, append

I have the following code:

```
receps =[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3]
listRecep = []
listNumRecep = []
class Line:
    def __init__(self,recep) :
        self.recep = recep
        
class Recep:
    recep=""
    lines = []

for recep in receps:
        l=Line(recep)
        if recep not in listNumRecep:
            listNumRecep.append(recep)
            r=Recep()
            r.recep=recep
            r.lines.append(l)
            #print(l.recep)
            listRecep.append(r)
        else:
            for re in listRecep:
                if re.recep == recep:
                    re.lines.append(l)
                    #print(l.recep)
        
for re in listRecep:
    print (re.lines[0].recep)
```

Basically what i want is to store every lines "Line" of the same "Recep" into a list contained in a "Recept" object.
Then i print the recep of the first line.

So the output expected would be:

```
1
2
3
```

but actually i have

```
1
1
1
```

It looks like the first line is stored every time in the list and that's what I don't understand because when i print l.recep(commented lines) the correct output is printed so the problem is when the "Line" is affected to the "Recep".

Comment: Think carefully about why your code includes a line that looks like `self.recep = recep`, but does *not* include a line that looks like `self.lines = []`.

Comment: Also, please think about variable naming. When reading code, one would assume `recep` would be an instance of `Recep`, but it is an integer in one place, and a string in another; one would assume `re` would be the regexp package, but it isn't; `l` and `r` are understandable in a short snippet but would be hell in a longer code (also, one might think they stand for "left" and "right", when used close together). None of this is an error, as such, but makes errors very easy, and debugging hard.

Comment: Thank you for you answers this code is just a snippet example I made from the original code for the post but I still don't understand why the first line is stored in all recep objects

Comment: Ok I figured it out thank you very much